# Archiving files through winrar but when ran its slow to load

Tags: performance, archive, winrar

I have 3.5gb files that I used winrar archive sfx whenn its done its shows size of exe that i archived is 1.5gb , when i run it it takes about 10-20 seconds to load, is there a way to make it run instantly when try to open it? . the reason i want to archive the files so they can extract in a location on the hard drive so if there is another way to do it without using winrar that will be great as long as when i open the archived or extractable file it will open instantly instead of waiting to load for 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to WinRAR having to scan the SFX and reading the archive upon loading.  I would guess that the more files you have and the larger those files end up making the archive, the longer it will take to load. Another factor could be that you have a slow hard drive and so it takes longer to scan. If you really want to track down the issue and report it to the author you could use [Process Monitor](http://www.sysinternals.com/) to see what the SFX is doing that it takes so long. But I think the easiest thing you can do is try using a different compression program to create the SFX.